# Working in trunk, don't want to commit, want to move changes to branch

Tags: git

Say I am working off of trunk for a while, and then realizes that all my current changes should have gone into a feature branch.

Is it possible for me to move all my changes to a feature branch at this point and leave trunk/master clean?

Comment: Committed changes or uncommitted changes (or both?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes (note: assuming committed changes):

Create a new branch off trunk:
`git checkout -b my-feature-branch`

Checkout trunk again:
`git checkout trunk`

Reset trunk to state before your changes:
`git reset --hard <revision before your changes>`

Voila.

Answer (score 1):

Just checkout the topic branch with option `-m` (`--merge`) and commit as usual:

```
$ git checkout -m topic
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have uncommitted changes, use `git stash` to stash them.

Create a new branch `git checkout -b <new_branch>` and then apply it using `git stash apply`.

If you have both committed and uncommitted changes, stash them with `git stash`, then do what @jmosbech has written and then do `git stash apply` on the new branch.

Comment: There's no point in the `stash` in the first case, you can simply `git checkout -b <new_branch>` with the uncommitted changes.